# How to integrate Workfront with Tableau?

Tags: integration, tableau-api, workfront-api

I am trying to create custom reports in Workfront using Tableau. For this I want to do an integration between the two. I am new to API integrations and Tableau so I am unsure of how I should approach this. How can I get the data I want out of Workfront and input it to Tableau, and then have the Tableau generated reports displayed in Workfront? Should I be using Tableau's Extract API? How can I access the Workfront API and where am I supposed to make the query for the data I want from Workfront?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct connector between the two. A common solution (there are vendors who will provide this as a service if you cannot do it in-house) is to build your own data warehouse and begin pulling down data from Workfront and into your own DB. Add that DB as a data source to Tableau and you're good to go.